# MongoDB doesn't receive an insert/save when called from a handler

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm (seemingly) not able to write to the mongoDB from a handler (button press).
If I strip the code and run it in a console app in Main it works...

Here's the class

```
class TimeRegistration
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string Werk { get; set; }
    public string Shot { get; set; }
    public double Uren { get; set; }
    public string Opmerkingen { get; set; }

}
```

And here's the body of the button handler

```
private void buttonLog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
    MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
    MongoDatabase db = server.GetDatabase("timeregistration");

    var logs = db.GetCollection<TimeRegistration>("logs");

    foreach( DataGridViewRow dgRow in dataGridViewLog.Rows)
    {
        if (dgRow.Cells[0].Value == null) continue;

        TimeRegistration log = new TimeRegistration();

        log.Name = Environment.UserName;
        log.Date = dateTimePickerLog.Value;

        if (dgRow.Cells[0].Value != null) log.Project       = dgRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        if (dgRow.Cells[1].Value != null) log.Werk          = dgRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        if (dgRow.Cells[2].Value != null) log.Shot          = dgRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        if (dgRow.Cells[3].Value != null) log.Uren          = Convert.ToDouble(dgRow.Cells[3].Value);
        if (dgRow.Cells[4].Value != null) log.Opmerkingen   = dgRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();

        logs.Save(log);//, saveOptions);   
    }
}
```

So my question is why would this run inside the Main of a console application but not inside the handler of a button in my winforms app.

Thanks!

Edit1: I made sure it's not a firewall issue.

Edit2: Taking it out of the handler and into a class on it's own makes it work. Still no clue why though.

Comment: Is there an error that occurs when it doesn't work from the handler? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: No error what-so-ever. But the SaveResult returns null, so it looks like the save method cannot be invoked. I have now taken it out of the handler (saveClass) and it works... weird.

Comment: @JHN: Can you show what you have in database after console app execution? Also can you execute console app twice and see two records in a database?

Comment: @AndrewOrsich if I clear the database from the commandline with db.timeregistration.drop() and then run db.timeregistration.find() after a insert/save it is just empty. 
Running it from the console app accurately inserts new records on every run.
My situation is a winforms app that loads (button press) a new winform app to register time/hours to Mongo. If I just offload the db routines to a static class and invoke the method with the data values it works. So I'm sticking to that, but it's a weird thing.

Comment: @JHN: Can you mark your _id field with `BsonId` attibute and explicitly initialize it via `ObjectId.Generate()`. After this come back to us with results.

Answer (score 0):

This could be your Mongo driver swallowing exceptions. It is possible to specify different Write Concerns for different operations, and the lowest concern swallows everything.

Try [calling `getLastError()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command) (or the C# equivalent - I'm from the Java world) to see what's gone wrong.

Write Concerns for Java are detailed [here](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html).